# Creating demo Data to all apps and keeping it in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
# Config files
COPY config /actinbox_config/
COPY script /actinbox_script/
COPY database /actinbox_db/

# Config pyenv
RUN echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="/root/.pyenv"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
# Config Nginx
    rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && \
    ln -s /actinbox_config/actinbox.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/actinbox.conf && \
# Config PostgreSQL
    rm /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf && \
    ln -s /actinbox_config/pg_hba.conf `enter code here`/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf && \
# Create DB & Restore database
    sh /actinbox_config/create_db_actinbox.sh && \
# Delete template folder
    rm -r /actinbox_db/
```

This is my dockerfile, I need suggestions and advise how to create a demo data that will be kept in docker image everytime I rerun the container.

Anyone who can help me with this? we are using postgre for db.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data in the container to be the same upon start (e.g. for integration tests) use the `COPY` command as you already did.

```
COPY demodata /demodata/
```

It will be "persisted" into the Docker image.

Another way is to mount a directory from your host to the Docker container.

```
docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory -it yourImage
```

Hereby you can modify the data while your container is up and running, share the same demo data across multiple containers and you won't loose your data when the container stops.